# How can we calculate deposition flux in terms of monolayer per second?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, soft-matter

In the nucleation and growth theory, I read the unit of deposition flux of atoms in a substrate in terms of monolayer per second. But could not figure it out how to calculate the flux in terms of monolayer per second.